# Make the image fit inside the div using background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I make the background image fit inside the `div` with specific dimensions. I tried with `object-fit` property but no luck. Could anyone please help?

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url("https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y");
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways and choose whatever suits you best.

**Using background-size**

You can `background-size: contain;` this way your image is stretched without cutting and also aspect ratio to fit your image using `background-url`

Also use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to only show your image *once* in the container.

Read more about `background-size` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Run snippet to see it working.

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
 background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y");
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

**Using background-size** with *height* and *width*

You can have max `height` and `width` of the image set to `100%`

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y");
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the property `background-size` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```css
div.image {
       background-image: url('https://gravatar.com/avatar/dba6bae8c566f9d4041fb9cd9ada7741?d=identicon&f=y');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```